# Cannot locate SSIS conversion file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\binn\DtwTypeConversion.xml

Tags: ssis

I am using SQL Server data tools and Sql Server 2012. Started learning SSIS.
While using sql server import/export wizard, I am getting this error

> Source Information] Source Location : GT1\SQLEXPRESS Source Provider :
>   SQLNCLI11 Mapping file (to SSIS type): C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\MappingFiles\MSSQLToSSIS10.XML
>
> [Destination Information] Destination Location : GT1\SQLEXPRESS
>   Destination Provider : SQLNCLI11 Mapping file (to SSIS type):
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\DTS\MappingFiles\MSSQLToSSIS10.XML
>
> [Conversion Table] Cannot locate SSIS conversion file C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\binn\DtwTypeConversion.xml

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following Microsoft link.  It provides some links to fixes based on the version of SQL Server in use.

https://support.microsoft.com/af-za/help/2938476/fix-errors-when-you-use-export-import-data-wizard-to-move-data-in-sql

Hope this helps.